# Google/Android : How to verify an in-app purchase if I don't have an API?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I own a quizz/game app and I offer in-app purchases (more questions, essentially).

Google said I have now to verify/approve every purchase made on my app, but they can't tell me how I can do it. It seems to me you need an API to to so, but my app doesn't.

In Google Play Console, it's not possible either.

Any other solutions you see, so that I am not ruined in the following months ?

Thank you a lot

I tried using the Google Play Console : did not work.

I can't see where I can verify a "pending" status if I don't have an API.

But I am not a developer and so maybe I'm wrong.